# How to wallpaper on android and iOS device in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, wallpapermanager

I'm creating a wallpaper app and I want to change the device wallpaper (like the Home and lock screen wallpaper). I'm showing lots of sites and videos but I didn't get answers properly. Can you please guys help me step by step process.

Answer (score 0):

In android
you can change wallpaper of device lock screen and home screen both by using this package in flutter.

You can use of this package for ios also

[just go to this package page and show it's description and follow it if any confusion then i will assist you](https://pub.dev/packages/wallpaper_manager)

Comment: Whenever using this package get this error while running app **Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:**

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/async_wallpaper.    You can use this wallpaper as well also

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/wallpaper_manager_flutter.  You can also it.

Comment: this package has not null safety so it's showing error

Comment: If You want to do native side code then you must follow this article https://codesearchonline.com/wallpaper-app/